# How to add a title slide to a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a title slide to a video.

I've the title image and I created a mp4 out of it using:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -f image2 -i slide.png -i silence.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -tune stillimage  -strict experimental -t ${INTRO_LENGTH} slide.mp4
```

And then I joined the slide using:

```
ffmpeg -i slide.mp4 slide.mpg
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 video.mpg
cat slide.mpg video.mpg > video-with-slides.mpg
ffmpeg -i video-with-slides.mpg video-with-slides.mp4
```

But the final output file is way larger than the input video (6X or more). Is there any simpler/better way to add a title slide to a video?

Answer (score 0):

Use the slide.mp4 and video.mp4 directly without transcoding into .mpg file (you lost quality). Forget the `cat` because cat will not update pts and at the end you will a demux/remux action to update the PTS of the resulting video.

So from here, I would say taht you have 2 options:

- **ffmpeg** syntax, **concat** is describe [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)

The syntax is a bit complex. I previously followed that tutorial using still image, but in your case, you could use the **concat protocol** or the **Concatenation of files with different codecs**.

- an alternative option could be **avisynth**, create a .avs script like below, and use it as input of ffmpeg

  ```
   S1 = ImageSource("static.png", end = 300, use_DevIL=true)
   S2 = DirecShowSource if your are under windows to read the Video
   S1 + S2
  ```